# Review the current week's agenda

Tags: org-mode

I learned to review the jobs get done in the current week following the instruction:

[The Org Manual: Weekly/daily agenda](https://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html)

Press C-c a and get

[image]

Continue to strike a, I get a single day's agenda of today rather than a week.

[image]

Tried M-x org-agenda-week-view and get the next week's agenda.

[image]

How could I get an agenda of this week starting from Monday.

The docs stats:

> For weekly agendas, the default is to start on the previous Monday (see org-agenda-start-on-weekday).

but it seems not the truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>M-x customize-variable</kbd> `org-agenda-span`

*Customize* buffer for the variable appears(choose day/week/month etc.);
This variable defines default **time span** of org agenda list.